# Error when mask ALOS DSM with elevation greater than 500

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

when i am trying to mask ALOS DSM with elevation greater than 500 (DSM.gte(500) = greather than 500),
i got error said : 'Line 8: DSM.gte is not a function'

```
 // Load or import ALOS dataset.
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('JAXA/ALOS/AW3D30/V3_2');

// Select the elevation mask.
var DSM = dataset.select('DSM');

// Create a binary mask.
var mask = DSM.gte(500);

// Update the composite mask with the DSM mask.
var maskedComposite = median.updateMask(mask);
Map.addLayer(maskedComposite, visParams, 'masked');
```

here is the link of the scripts:
https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/68703708fc01b2566c705cea5ee1dee7

Can someone help?

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks within your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AW3D30 dataset is not a single image, it's an image collection.  If you want to treat it as a single image then you should `mosaic` the collection into a single image.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('JAXA/ALOS/AW3D30/V3_2').mosaic()
```